# TimeGenerated Column Value to be in UTC+8 by default in Log Analytics Workspace in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am currently a beginner in Microsoft Azure and came across a scenario where I need to get the TimeGenerated Value of Query result to be in UTC+8 by default i.e., The moment I click on ‘Run’ for the Query result, it should provide me the TimeGenerated column value in UTC+8 instead of UTC.
Is there a way to achieve this?
I can see an option below the result of ‘Display Time Zone’ but that is valid only for that current   session of Azure Portal.

Please guide me how can I set the UTC+8 timezone by default.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in way to set a default time zone for the `TimeGenerated` column, It is a in-built setting set to UTC by default. Date Time value in Kusto is always in UTC as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats).

But there are work around to get the local time for the `TimeGenerated` column.

1. At the bottom of the `logs` in `log analytics` where we can change the time to local time zone or other time zones for viewing purpose. As shown below.

[image]

2. It can be added manually using query:
   `extend Local_time = datetime_utc_to_local(TimeGenerated,'Asia/Kolkata')`
   For reference and different time zones check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-utc-to-local-function).

[image]